# Eclipse: Create getters with java.util.Optional for String members

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation

In eclipse you can easily create getters and setters for your classes' fields.

Before:

```
package main;

public class TestClass {
    private String someString;
    private boolean someBoolean;
}
```

After creating the getters (as we don't care for setters in this question):

```
package main;

public class TestClass {
    private String someString;
    private boolean someBoolean;

    /**
     * @return the someString
     */
    public String getSomeString() {
        return someString;
    }

    /**
     * @return the someBoolean
     */
    public boolean isSomeBoolean() {
        return someBoolean;
    }
}
```

But if you do not initialize the `String` value `getSomeString()` will return `null`, meaning that if I want to work with the `String` in the calling object, I have to always check if for `null` first.

To avoid this I found some solutions:

1. Initialize the Strings immediately at their declaration: `private String someString = "";`
2. [Reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293500/initialize-all-string-members-with-an-empty-string)
3. `return someString == null ? someString : "";`
4. Using [java.util.Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)
5. there are probably many more ways...

While writing this question I figured out that probably for the simple `String` case the first method should work best: I can easily initialize the `String`s to whatever I like and am done.

The reflection approach linked above seemed okay, but a bit messy to handle 
exceptions where a `String` should not be initialized with the empty string.

The null check is okay but now with Java 8 the last method, employing `java.util.Optional` feels like the right way to do that. I would do it like this:

```
public String getSomeString() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(someString).orElse("");
}
```

Is it possible to get eclipse's code templates into creating getters like this one for Strings (or all non-primitive types) only?

The standard template used (see Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Code Templates -> Code -> Getter body) is:

```
return ${field};
```

I can replace it with

```
return java.util.Optional.ofNullable(${field}).orElse("");
```

which helps for Strings - but for all other types it obviously fails.
So I tried

```
${:import(java.util.Optional)}
return Optional.ofNullable(${field}).orElse(new ${return_type}());
```

which is not allowed, because `Variable 'return_type' is not known.` and additionally the `${:import(java.util.Optional)}` is not solved as [the help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm) makes you believe (I assume it is because Code Templates are just a stricter subset of Templates, more or less). The first makes sense - if `${return_type}` is a primitive, this is likely to fail.

Is there a way to make it happen that eclipse generates such custom getters for me? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911179/3004221) allows to create such getter for one field, but that would mean I had to do it for each field individually. Is it possible to also just have it done by Source -> Generate getters/setters (or any other similar method)?

Or do you think it's best to initialize such objects at their declaration anyway?

Comment: If possible, make your field final, and assign them in the constructor. You'll make your class immutable.
* http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162665/immutable-class

Comment: Eventually I want to be able to update the values with an http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html so final fields will not help, I think.

Comment: But giving it a second thought, I could actually wrap the data inside an immutable class and return copies of the object. I will try that, thank you very much!